# mysql how to derive month/month name, last_day(),quarter number,year based on random date column while insertion in a single transaction dynamically

Tags: mysql

mysql how to derive month/month name, last_day(),quarter number,year based on random date column while insertion in a single transaction dynamically? 
For e.g., I have a table like 'test'

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `KEY` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MTH_END_DT` DATE NOT NULL,
  `DT` DATE NOT NULL,
  `FINCL_YEAR_MTH_NUM` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINCL_YEAR` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINCL_YEAR_QTR_NUM` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`KEY`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and my insert statement is like

```
INSERT INTO test (`KEY`,`MTH_END_DT`,`DT`,`FINCL_YEAR_MTH_NUM`,`FINCL_YEAR`,`FINCL_YEAR_QTR_NUM`)
    VALUES (
    DEFAULT,
    [need TO derive based ON third COLUMN LIKE LAST_DAY(date1)],
    DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE('2017-07-01'), DATE('2019-03-31'))), DATE('2017-07-01'))) AS date1, 
    [need TO derive based ON third COLUMN LIKE MONTH(date1)],
    [need TO derive based ON third COLUMN LIKE YEAR(date1)],
    [need TO derive based ON third COLUMN LIKE QUARTER(date1)]
    );
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: If you assume third column as date1(which is going to generate random date string dynamically), based on that column date, other columns need to derived like corresponding month number(e.g.,1)/name (e.g., january),last_day(date1)(e.g., 2018-01-31), financial month number, quarter and year for the same.

Comment: How you generate  the random date???

Comment: It's right there in third column of insert statement using timestampadd, timestampdiff, rand function and also date function.

Comment: seems not possible  to me  because you can't use alias column in insert  .. (because there is not a precedence between the column ) ..and then you have note the same values for others columns that you think to refere to 3th column  .  so you should generate you random  value  on with a sql var  .. or externaly  using a server side function